# Using jQuery how to create unique ids for all ahrefs in page

Tags: jquery

Assuming if all the ahrefs in my website do not have an id number and look like this:

```
<a href="http://mydomainurl1.com">First URL</a>
```

I want to add a unique id number to each of the ahrefs in the page that match a certain pattern to look like this:

```
<a href="http://mydomainurl1.com" id="24"> First URL </a>
```

**Here is my code:**
*Please note:* even though the code below successfully assigns an id to the ahref where stackoverflow.com/jobs is found in the page, if there are two or more occurrences of stackoverflow.com/jobs ahrefs in the page the code assigns the SAME random id number to all ahref occurrences of stackoverflow.com/jobs in the page. (Since I wanted to keep my company website information private I substituted it for stackoverflow.com in the below code.)

```html
var array = [];
var number = 0;
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for(var i=0, max=links.length; i<max; i++) {
    array.push(links[i].href);
    number = i + 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $("a[href$='stackoverflow.com/jobs']").attr("id",number);                
}
```

Comment: Well, you could just increment `number` in each iteration to avoid that.

Comment: It's worth noting that creating id attributes are runtime is generally a code-smell. You don't need to do this to identify elements. Depending on your use case you can get a reference to the element from an event handler, or by using DOM traversal methods to relate elements together in common HTML structures

Comment: Thanks Rory McCrossan. The code $('a:not([id])').prop('id', i => i + 1); added a unique id to all the ahrefs on my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `for` loop ..  It would be simpler to use jQuery's `.each()`  .. That way you can use `$(this)` and easily change the `attr` of `id`.

Something like this should solve your issue.

```
var number = 77;

$('a*').each(function(){  // This selector is where you'd look for things like a[href$='stackoverflow.com/jobs']
    number++;
    var rand_number =  number * Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $(this).attr("id",rand_number);
});
```

**With your selector**

You're going to want to use `^` instead of `$` in your `href` selector -- Meaning *"Starts with"*

```js
var number = 77;

$("a[href^='stackoverflow.com/jobs']").each(function(){ // Use ^ instead of $
    number++;
    var rand_number =  number * Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    $(this).attr("id",rand_number);
    console.log($(this).attr('href') + " now has ID " + rand_number)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="stackoverflow.com/jobs/1">First URL</a><br />
<a href="stackoverflow.com/jobs/2">Second URL</a><br />
<a href="stackoverflow.com/jobs/3">Third URL</a><br />
<a href="example.com">Non Selected in .each()</a> <!-- This URL will not set ID -->
```

Comment: Hi Zak, Thank you. ^ did not work. $ worked. It helped to add unique ids to the targeted ahrefs on the page.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! ..  I figured you were wanting `blah/jobs/1`, `blah/jobs/2`, `blah/jobs/3` --  My bad!